# Copy and Rename files using mapping file

Tags: batch-file

My company recently migrated from one payroll system to another. I've used excel to dump all the files to a list with their path and mapped the old employees ID's to the new system.  What I have now is a spreadsheet with old file name, current file path, and new file name.   Is there a way for a .bat script to use this spreadsheet to copy and rename each file?

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with Microsoft Excel. For that, what you'll need to do is export your spreadsheet to a _plain text_, csv file. Then using a [tag:for-loop], you could parse each line for the data you require. To learn how to do that start by opening a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the 'enter' key, and read the information presented to you. Pay particular notice of the `for /f` loop with its `tokens` and `delimiters` options. Additionally, search this site as there are thousands of questions on here relating to parsing a csv file.

Comment: Also recommend fleshing out your first script by simply outputting the operations you think want to perform, such as; `echo copy %%A %%B` or some such.  And do work with an offline/backup data set first, until your sure it works properly.